# Decodificar Json con varios json arrays

Tags: java, android, json, jsonarray

Tengo un `Json` que recojo de un `JsonRequest` asi

```
{
  "multas": [
    {
      "id": "222",
      "title": "Folio: 222\nFecha:27/03/2019\nMunicipio:Zapopan\nDireccion:555 calle falsa",
      "rightImage": "/images/categorias/right_go.png",
      "folio": "222",
      "fecha": "27/03/2019 00:00",
      "lt": "20.660852",
      "lg": "-103.381558",
      "imagen": "http://flexorpoint.mx/mobilemanager/_isue_/images/autos/min/4_1_08082014_0804.jpeg",
      "placa": "JSK01",
      "municipio": "Zapopan",
      "direccion": "555 calle falsa",
      "precio": "256.35000000000002",
      "infracciones": null,
      "font": {
        "fontSize": "13dp"
      },
      "color": "#000"
    },
    {
      "id": "221",
      "title": "Folio: 221\nFecha:27/03/2019\nMunicipio:Zapopan\nDireccion:555 calle falsa",
      "rightImage": "/images/categorias/right_go.png",
      "folio": "221",
      "fecha": "27/03/2019 00:00",
      "lt": "20.660852",
      "lg": "-103.381558",
      "imagen": "http://flexorpoint.mx/mobilemanager/_isue_/images/autos/min/4_1_08082014_0804.jpeg",
      "placa": "JSK01",
      "municipio": "Zapopan",
      "direccion": "555 calle falsa",
      "precio": "256.35000000000002",
      "infracciones": null,
      "font": {
        "fontSize": "13dp"
      },
      "color": "#000"
    },
    {
      "id": "220",
      "title": "Folio: 220\nFecha:27/03/2019\nMunicipio:Zapopan\nDireccion:555 calle falsa",
      "rightImage": "/images/categorias/right_go.png",
      "folio": "220",
      "fecha": "27/03/2019 00:00",
      "lt": "20.660852",
      "lg": "-103.381558",
      "imagen": "http://flexorpoint.mx/mobilemanager/_isue_/images/autos/min/4_1_08082014_0804.jpeg",
      "placa": "JSK01",
      "municipio": "Zapopan",
      "direccion": "555 calle falsa",
      "precio": "256.35000000000002",
      "inf`racciones": null,
      "font": {
        "fontSize": "13dp"
      },
      "color": "#000"
    }
  ]
}
```

y quiero tener por separado cada uno de los arreglos que el `json` tiene, como logro identificar o separarlos ?

```
  JSONObject multasJSON=response.getJSONObject("multas");
```

asi tendria el `Json` pero como lo separo ?

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿la variable `multasJSON` es la que muestras arriba en tu código?

Comment: Si, es la que contiene el `array` de arriba, pero como ves tiene varios elementos adentro del mismo arra entonces quiero saber como puedo separar esos elementos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu response es un `JSONObject` ya que viene en `{}` pero el elemento multa es `JSONArray` viene dentro de `[]`:

```
JSONObject  jsResponse = new JSONObject(response);// pasas tu response a un JSONObject

JSONArray jsonArray = jsResponse.getJSONArray("multas"); // a ese JSONObject le extraes un JSONArray llamado multas
```

Ya luego lo recorres para extraer sus valores:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject elemento = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String title = elemento.getString("title")
 }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, saludos :D